# Can you explain this "Theory of Everything"?

Tags: units, theory-of-everything

I recently come across with an amazing equation of Theory of Everything; I wonder if TOE has been formulated (???) I found this equation on a website, check it out http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2013/01/04/the-world-of-everyday-experience-in-one-equation/. While seeing briefly this equation, I simply don't understand what this means because there are no explanations of all the units used in this formula (e.g. ψ, Φ, i, A, α, etc). What is W? Can you explain what the units are and what all of these mean? Does this formula be the real formula of TOE? Thank you :) [image: Equation of TOE (?)]

Comment: Nope, that's not what physicist would call a TOE, but I think something like this made some folks in the T-shirt business good money.

Comment: You are essentially asking us to explain the whole of quantum field theory to you, which is *far too broad*. Also, this would only be the description for a theory of everything if the gravity part didn't have...issues.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77663/2451 and links therein.

Comment: it is from mainstream lectures of Sean Caroll ( professor at Caltech ) ...

Comment: @igael: I hope this is taken out of context or Sean Caroll should be ashamed of himself to present a summation of incompatible theory Lagrangians as a TOE.